# Hide constructor of an inherited class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

Please take a look at this example:

```
public class X
{
    public X()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I'm X");
    }
}

public class Y : X
{
    public Y()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I'm Y");
    }
}
```

When executing the command `Y y = new Y();`, two message boxes appear - first "I'm X", then "I'm Y".

How can I get rid of this behaviour? I need to stop the constructor of `X` when making a new `Y`.

Answer (score 4):

The default constructor from X will be called unless you specifically call a different one.
Try this:

```
public class X {
    public X() {
        MessageBox.Show("I'm X");
    }
    protected X(int dummy){
    }
}

public class Y : X {
    public Y() : X(0) { // will call other constructor
        MessageBox.Show("I'm Y");
    }
}
```

This will just prevent the default constructor from being called.

However, based on your question - "what I need is to stop the constructor of X when making a new Y.", I'm not sure you understand the basics of object inheritance... If you don't want to create a new X when creating a new Y, why would you derive Y from X? You know that inheritance is an is-a relationship, right? In your case, Y is-a X...

Answer (score 3):

You can use factory methods:

```
public class X {
    private X() {}
    protected virtual void Init(){
        MessageBox.Show("I'm X");    
    }
    public static GetX() {
        X ret = new X();
        ret.Init();
        return ret;
    }
}

public class Y : X {
    private Y() {}
    protected virtual void Init(){
        MessageBox.Show("I'm Y");    
    }
    public static GetY() {
        Y ret = new Y();
        ret.Init();
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider that `Y` is a subtype of `X`. More specifically, `Y` needs an `X` to be complete. So, if you construct a `Y`, it'll need to be able to create an `X` in *some* fashion. That is to say, you will need to always call *a* constructor, but which one is up to you. You can specify which one via the strategy in Luchian's answer:

```
public Y () : X (...)
```

Wherein you choose which constructor of `X` based on the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This would do the trick, though you probably should avoid doing whatever it is in the constructor. The constructor should only be used for initial initialization.

```
public class X
{
    public X()
    {
        if (this.GetType() == typeof(X))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm X");
        }
    }

    public class Y : X
    {
        public Y()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm Y");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Y y = new Y();
        }
    }
}
```